# Iframe rotatório em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de corrigir o seguinte *script* para ficar da maneira que eu preciso.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function randomIframe(obj){
var ends = new Array();
ends[0] = "http://www.terra.com.br";
ends[1] = "http://www.uol.com.br";
ends[2] = "http://www.bol.com.br";
ends[3] = "http://www.cade.com.br";
ends[4] = "http://www.baixaki.com.br";

var i = Math.round(Math.random()*ends.length-1);

obj.location.replace(ends[i]);

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="randomIframe(publicidade)">

<iframe name="publicidade" width="500" height="100"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu queria saber se tem alguma maneira do `<iframe>` ficar dentro do próprio *script*, não abaixo do `<body>`, algo que use `document.write` dentro do *script* e um `window.onload = random_iframe` por exemplo. Para ficar somente algo dentro do `<script>` até o `</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

usei jquery para fazer o load no iframe veja:

```js
function randomIframe(obj){
var ends = new Array();
  
ends[0] = "http://www.terra.com.br";
ends[1] = "http://www.uol.com.br";
ends[2] = "http://www.bol.com.br";
ends[3] = "http://www.cade.com.br";
ends[4] = "http://www.baixaki.com.br";
var i = Math.round(Math.random()*ends.length-1);
obj.location.replace(ends[i]);
  
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $("#publicidade").load(randomIframe(this));    
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="publicidade" width="500" height="100" id='publicidade'></iframe>
```

Se você quiser que ele abra no tamanho especificado pelo seu iframe, use o atributo `src` para colocar o caminho de um html que abrirá toda a página iframe, exemplo :

```html
// Pagina que contem o iframe

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Exemplo</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe name="publicidade" src='teste2.html' id='publicidade' height="300" width="500"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>

// Pagina que carregará todo site

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Exemplo</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   </head>
   <body>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function randomIframe(obj) {
            var ends = new Array();

            ends[0] = "http://www.terra.com.br";
            ends[1] = "http://www.uol.com.br";
            ends[2] = "http://www.bol.com.br";
            ends[3] = "http://www.cade.com.br";
            ends[4] = "http://www.baixaki.com.br";
            var i = Math.round(Math.random() * ends.length - 1);
            obj.location.replace(ends[i]);
         }
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").load(randomIframe(this));
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ótima solução, porém os sites não estão abrindo dentro do iframe, a página inteira é redirecionada... Além disso, é possivel deixar o iframe dentro do primeiro script com o "document.write"? Por exemplo document.write('<iframe name="publicid....) Obrigado

Comment: editei, salva em um html e testa, lembrando que são 2 paginas uma que vai carregar tudo e outra que contem o iframe com a resolução desejada.